# MoreLinq ExceptBy with only one matching property

Tags: c#, linq, tuples, morelinq

I have 2 different items that I'm trying to perform the except by method using the more linq library. The only thing that is common between both items is a single string called Symbol. Item 1 is a list of tuples and Item 2 is a database table that I open with linq

**Item 1:**

```
Tuple<string Symbol, string Market, List<Class1>, List<Class2>>
```

**Item 2:**

```
List<TableClass>

TableClass {
string Symbol;
decimal Price;
bool isSold; }
```

Here is the code I attempted. I'm trying to return all elements from Item1 that don't exist in Item2:

```
Item1.ExceptBy(Item2.Select(k => k.Symbol), e => e.Symbol);
```

This doesn't work because Item1 and Item2 are completely different types

> The type arguments for method 'MoreEnumerable.ExceptBy(IEnumerable, IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type
>   arguments explicitly.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected results (so we can see what you are trying to achieve).

Comment: Additionally, can you confirm whether you are happy for this to occur in-memory (rather than in the database itself)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I keep an extension method handy for doing left outer joins:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> LeftOuterJoin<TLeft, TRight, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TLeft> leftSeq,
    IEnumerable<TRight> rightSeq,
    Func<TLeft, TKey> keySelectorLeft,
    Func<TRight, TKey> keySelectorRight,
    Func<TLeft, TRight, TResult> projectionSelector)
{
    return leftSeq
        .GroupJoin(
            rightSeq,
            keySelectorLeft,
            keySelectorRight,
            (leftItem, rightItems) => new { leftItem, rightItems })
        .SelectMany(
            x => x.rightItems.DefaultIfEmpty(),
            (x, rightItem) => projectionSelector(x.leftItem, rightItem));
}
```

So now we can:

```
tuples.LeftOuterJoin(list, t => t.Symbol, k => k.Symbol, (t,k) => (t,k))
      .Where(x => x.k == null)
      .Select(x => x.t)
```

...and this will give us all the items from the tuple list with a `Symbol` property that does not have a corresponding item in the other list with the same `Symbol`. Right?